# How to use "this" on inner div from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover, this

I have a quick web program which when you hover over another image, a small box pops up underneath.

I set up a quick function like so:

```
$('.indArtistBox').hover(function(){
    $('.description').show();
});
```

This problem is I want to some how incorporate `this`, because I only want the description to be shown on the `.indArtistBox` that is being hovered on.

I tried `$(this).('.description')`, but that obviously didn't work. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

Use `find`.

```
$(this).find(".classOfYourSubObject")./* ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `this` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) for the selector:

```
$('.description', this).show();
```

Internally this is implemented with jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, so it is equivalent to:

```
$(this).find('.description').show();
```

If `.description'` is a direct child of `.indArtistBox`, [it seems to be faster in most browsers](http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find/54) to use jQuery's [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method instead as this method only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$(this).children('.description').show();
```

Comment: jQuery seems to thoroughly confuse the meaning of "context" (which is why your link is to the selector entry, not a "context" entry). Here "context" means the root or parent element that the selector will be applied to. The documentation does not explain it at all.

Comment: @RobG - I don't understand what you mean, isn't "context" something like "surrounding elements" in this case, so if you specify the "context" for the selector to be applied to, does it not make sense that the "context" you give is the parent element, as it contains all the surrounding elements? Also, the link is to the exact spot in the jQuery documentation where it showa how to specify the "context" which a selector should be applied to.

Comment: The term context is used in different places to mean different things, e.g. the "parent" element for a selector (as in this case), the "this" keyword of a function, in a "boolean context" (whatever that means) and so on. In ECMAScript, "context" means only one thing: execution context. None of jQuery's uses of context align with ECMAscipt's meaning, hence the confusion. Note that it doesn't actually explain what "context" means for a selector, it's just assumed the user will work it out.

Comment: @RobG - Ok, the link does explain it though, you just have to scroll down a little (there's no clickable anchor provided directly to that piece of information on the page), but looking in the source for an ID allows me to provide [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) instead. I'll update the answer.